# libcore.io.ErrnoException open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created  the simplest program in Android studio 0.3.7.

```
public class test extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tt;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sett);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            tt.setText("Running");
            break;
}
}
}
```

but i result i find error in logcat. How to avoid this error?
i tried to find the solution but didnt find.
Also i find that other my projects have this problem too.

```
12-07 15:31:57.653      232-269/? E/ActivityManager﹕ mtprof entry can not found!
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/mtprof/status: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:448)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.mtProf(ActivityRecord.java:852)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:653)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$Token.windowsDrawn(ActivityRecord.java:225)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage(WindowManagerService.java:6994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:754)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: This looks like an issue in code that ships with Android (/proc is a way for the kernel to export information to userspace, so something missing there suggests a userspace vs kernel mismatch of version or supported features), rather than one in your program.  Does your program fail to operate in the expected way?  Are you running on an emulator or on a device?

Comment: this problem appear only on the real device(4.0.4) . I tested on real device (4.4 Android) a few sec ago and everything was fine.

Comment: How can i avoid this problem  on the android 4.0.4 ?

Comment: You've not yet explained if there *is* a functional problem, or anything more than understandable unease about the log message.  It seems to me that the log message may be a result of a minor mistake in  a particular Android build, in which case there's likely nothing you can do about it other than ignore it on the devices where it occurs.

Comment: I have tested in  few different projects and its not a functional problem.